# Show salary history in a table format from a listing format?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2000, pivot

I'm sure this won't be a difficult question for the hardcore SQL geeks, but I need some help. This is for SQL Server 2000 (inherited projects!).

I have a table of salary listings that look like this:

```
EmployeeID  |  EffectiveDate  | Salary
1           |   2/1/2011      | 500
1           |   6/1/2011      | 600
1           |   12/1/2011     | 650
```

I need to create a query that will output these salaries by month for a given year. So the output would be like

```
EmployeeID  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec
1           | 500 | 500 | 500 | 500 | 500 | 500 | 600 | 600 | 600 | 600  | 600 | 600 | 650
```

I know there must be a way to do this effectively with SQL, I just can't seem to get it right. Obviously, I would be naming the month columns above with SQL such as 
SELECT EmployeeID, 'Jan' AS Jan, 'Feb' AS Feb, etc but the rest of the statement is harder since I'm looking for ranges.

Comment: Are you sure you need all done in SQL (remove C# tag than) or you can do display portion in C# (not sure what the question is than as it would be simple `WHERE EffectiveDate>@StartYear and EffectiveDate<@EndYear`)

Comment: That would give me multiple results since the salary can change within the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2000 it does not have a `PIVOT` function, so you will have to replicate this using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement. Similar to this:

```
select  employeeid,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 1 then Salary end) as Jan,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 2 then Salary end) as Feb,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 3 then Salary end) as Mar,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 4 then Salary end) as Apr,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 5 then Salary end) as May,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 6 then Salary end) as Jun,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 7 then Salary end) as Jul,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 8 then Salary end) as Aug,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 9 then Salary end) as Sep,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 10 then Salary end) as Oct,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 11 then Salary end) as Nov,
  sum(case when DatePart(Month, EffectiveDate) = 12 then Salary end) as Dec
from  yourtable
group by employeeid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61ed5/2)

Edit, based on your comments above carrying over the value from one month to the next, here is a solution that might work for you.

```
declare @query as nvarchar(max) = '',
  @rowcount as int = 1,
  @pivotrow as int,
  @currentMonthSalary as int = 0,
  @priorMonthSalary as int = 0,
  @employeeid int 

select distinct effectivedate
into #colspivot
from yourtable

while @rowcount <= 12 -- loop thru each month
  begin

    set @pivotrow = (select top 1 datepart(month, effectivedate)
                        from #colspivot
                        order by datepart(month, effectivedate))

    select @currentMonthSalary = salary, @employeeid = EmployeeID
            from yourtable
            where datepart(month, effectivedate) = @pivotrow

    if @pivotrow = @rowcount
        begin
            insert into FinalData (employeeid, effectivemonth, salary)
            select @employeeid, cast(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, @pivotrow, 0) -1) as varchar(3)), @currentMonthSalary

            set @query = @query + ', sum(case when effectivemonth = ''' +  cast(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, @pivotrow, 0) -1) as varchar(3)) + ''' 
                                        then ' + cast(@currentMonthSalary as varchar(10)) + ' end) as '+ cast(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, @pivotrow, 0) -1) as varchar(3))

            delete from #colsPivot where datepart(month, effectivedate) = @pivotRow

            set @priorMonthSalary = @currentMonthSalary
        end
    else
        begin
            insert into FinalData (employeeid, effectivemonth, salary)
            select @employeeid, cast(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, @rowcount, 0) -1) as varchar(3)), @priorMonthSalary

            set @query = @query + ', sum(case when effectivemonth = ''' + cast(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, @rowcount, 0) -1) as varchar(3)) + '''  
                        then ' +  cast(@priorMonthSalary as varchar(10)) + ' end) as '+cast(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, @rowcount, 0) -1) as varchar(3))
        end

    if @rowcount <= 12
      set @rowcount = @rowcount + 1
  end

set @query = 'select employeeid '+ @query 
              + ' from FinalData group by employeeid;'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca5b5/1).  I created a new table `FinalData` to store the data for each month while I loop through creating the sql statement.

Comment: OK, makes sense. But, it if it wasn't clear in my first message, there are only table entries where there is a change. So if there is a change in Feb and then May, the table results for March and April should be the same as Feb. Your answer wouldn't account for that, right?

Comment: I guess it slightly different from what Jim Beam wanted - my understanding is that he have function defined be 3 values, but wants to have results for any time `Salary(month) = {select Salary where EffectiveDate.NoDay <= TheMonthDate.NoDay }`

Comment: @alexei true, let me see how to proceed

Comment: @JimBeam please see my edit, I creating a dynamic version that should work in SQL Server 2000 to produce the result that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - the above should work. I also implemented something similar to what Alexei suggested. With the lack of a PIVOT function, using the subquery might also be just as effective.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
Select  EmployeeID, [Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec]
From
(
    Select EmployeeID, CAST(DateName(MONTH,EffectiveDate) as varchar(3)) as Mon, Salary
        From Employees

) as SourceTable

PIVOT
(
    Sum(Salary)
    For Mon in ( [Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec] )
) as PivotTable
```

It produces exact same result as the result you showed in your output sample.

Comment: Sorry but Pivot is not supported in SQL Server 2000, which is what I'm using (for better or worse!)

Comment: @JimBeam: My mistake! I didn't see the tag of SQL Server 2000 :(